# Why does Map() === Map() evaluate to true?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

In ImmutableJS, two different empty map objects evaluate to true. Why is this the case? I assumed it had something to do with comparison based on hashing or something like that.

Comment: It just returns exactly the same value from both calls.

Comment: why should it have to create something new for something that can't change?

Comment: "Turns out I have a scenario where this comparison needs to be false." sounds like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: "I need to know when a new object was created." but no new object *was* created.

Comment: Seems like you want to do: `new Map() === new Map()`.

Comment: new Map() === new Map() evaluates to false

Comment: @claytronicon That's the point. They are two different instances. Where using just `Map()` from immutable will not make a new instance and use the same reference as before.

Comment: @gkelly OP is talking about `Map() === Map()` with `Map` from ImmutableJS, which is already explained in the question. Not `new Map() === new Map()` which would do what OP expects to do.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko sorry, poor choice of words. I should have said 'was intended to be false' rather than 'needs to be false'.

Comment: @DanielA.White great point, I hadn't thought of this. I incorrectly assumed that Map() creates a new immutable object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not hashing nor any other kind of "magic", `immutablejs` returns exactly the same reference for both calls.

For instance, this is how it handles an empty map. It assigns the empty map to its own "global" scope and always reutilizes the same reference.

```
let EMPTY_MAP;
export function emptyMap() {
  return EMPTY_MAP || (EMPTY_MAP = makeMap(0));
}
```

https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js/blob/master/src/Map.js#L637

Answer (score 1):

You might work around it by adding some dummy object in your code, like:

```
const dummy = {key: "I am a dummy object"}
```

and always pass it as parameter when creating new Map. It is not ideal solution, but it will for sure return false when comparing one to another, even if both were created using the same object.